# How should I be cleaning up event/delegate refs in UIViewControllers to prevent mem leaks?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

Suppose you have an iOS app with a UINavigationController with three UIViewControllers pushed onto it: `vc1`, `vc2` and `vc3`.

`vc1` wants to get notified of when something happens on `vc2` and/or `vc3`. For example, when something gets saved on `vc2` or `vc3`, update `vc1` and automatically pop back to `vc1`. Easy. Just have `vc2` or `vc3` fire an event and have it be caught by `vc1`. Well, when the time comes to pop back to `vc1` the other two vc's won't get garbage collected because they hold a reference via the event subscription.

What's the best way to resolve this and get everything cleaned up when `vc1` subscribes to an event on `vc2`, similarly `vc2` to `vc3`?

Only thing I can think of is to define a public `CleanUp()` method so that when the nav controller pops back to `vc1` (and vc1 will have to detect this scenario somehow) it will call `vc2.CleanUp()`. If you had X number of vc's that would be a lot of cleanup that you'd have to write 'cause you'd have to, in a sense, bubble up the call through the line of popped vc's. Yuck.

How would you do this traditionally in obj-c and also, how would you do this in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the scenario you are describing above quite frequently. This is how I handle it:

Controller vc1 pushes vc2 onto the navigation stack, after it has subscribed to vc2's SaveClicked event. So I want to pop vc2 when this event occurs. Now, since vc2 will be popped when the SaveClicked event will be triggered, it suits us because we know that the event will only be used once. I also use anonymous methods for these situations when not much logic is needed, to keep things compact.

Inside vc1:

```
vc2 = new UIViewController(); //vc2 is a class variable
EventHandler vc2SaveClickedHandler = null;
vc2SaveClickedHandler = delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // Unsubscribe here
    vc2.SaveClicked -= vc2SaveClickedHandler;
    // Or, we could do:
    // UIViewController vc2Sender = sender as UIViewController;
    // vc2Sender.SaveClicked -= vc2SaveClickedHandler;

    // do some stuff

    // Pop vc2
    vc2.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);

}
vc2.SaveClicked += vc2SaveClickedHandler;
this.NavigationController.PushViewControllerAnimated(vc2, true);
```

So you can do the same for vc2 and vc3 and so on...

Comment: I tried this method of cleaning up event refs but it quickly gets complicated when `vc1` subscribes to more than one event where it wouldn't be right to unsubscribe to all events at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

iOS provides a simple and efficient observer pattern in the NSNotification class. It uses strings for queues, and I use it all the time to solve the kind of problem you mentioning.

The good thing about this approach is that vc1 doesn't need to know about vc2 and vc2 doesn't need to know about vc1. They can communicate without having a hard dependency, which really simplifies memory management.

Quick example:
first lets make vc1 subscribe to a "saveSelected" event, from the viewdidload or controller constructor:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver("saveSelected", (a)=>{
    this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);
});
```

Now, when vc2 save button is clicked, instead of calling vc1 or an event, it would post a notification with:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("saveSelected", otherdata);
```

Just to be safe, you can unregister vc1 from the notificationcenter in viewDidUnload() using the RemoveObserver method.

Comment: I've seen examples that use the NSNotificationCenter. Is it common to use this style of "eventing" on a MonoTouch application vs. using normal C# events?

Comment: "common" is subjective; I've been using it for the last year on all MonoTouch apps I've created and it works great. It's definitely common enough in iOS development, and at the end of the day, it's just a simple subpub pattern. Although the code ends up not being portable to Android/WP7, etc, you can either create a simple wrapper around the NSNotificationCenter class, or just create your custom class that works on all platforms.

Comment: I did a little bit of research. I think using NSNotificationCenter has the same pitfalls as using normal C# events. A reference to your observer is kept by the NSNotificationCenter until you remove the observer thus preventing garbage collection. Removing the observer in viewDidUnload() would also delay collection until the system decides to call unload and this happens only in low memory situations (it may never get called). This leaves my question unanswered.

Comment: No, in your example, the NSNotificationCenter will only have a reference to vc1, but not vc2 or vc3. So after the navigationcontroller drops the reference to those other controllers, vc2 and 3 can be garbage collected. You can force the collection to happen with GC.Collect();

Comment: You're right. It doesn't retain a ref to your observer. But there's another problem with this approach. The [iOS documentation](http://goo.gl/lo4Bq) says it "...does not retain its observers, therefore, you must ensure that you unregister observers. If you don't, you will generate a runtime error if the center sends a message to a freed object." Looks like there's no way around having to cleanup after yourself. Perhaps removing the observer in Dispose() would be better than in ViewDidUnload()?

Comment: So for example, vc2 would still somehow have to clean up all its observers if you popped from vc3 to vc1.

Comment: You're misunderstanding things. vc1 is not a observer of vc2. Vc1 observes events for the string "saveSelected". Vc1 doesn't know about vc2/3. You'll only need to remove the vc1 observer when VC1 gets unloaded.

Comment: Also, a good practice is to do registration of events on viewdidload and unregistration on viewdidunload, so that you can access the view  objects from the notification callback without causing issues because view objects don't exist anymore. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @AndrewYoung let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2824/discussion-between-eduardo-scoz-and-andrew-young)